# Display php time if not 00:00:00

Tags: php

How do I display the time only if it is not `00:00:00`?  This works, however, I question whether there is a less cryptic way of doing so.  Note that the datetimes provided will be standard MySQL datetime data types, and the desired datetimes to be displayed will vary.  Thanks

```
<?php
function formatDate($d)
{
    $f='Y-m-d'.((strlen($d)==19 && substr($d, -8)!='00:00:00')?' H:i:s':null);
    $date = new DateTime($d);
    return $date->format($f);
}
echo(formatDate("2014-11-02 02:04:05").'<br>');
echo(formatDate("2014-11-02 00:00:00").'<br>');
?>
```

Comment: Check this one, see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129817/getting-a-timestamp-for-today-at-midnight

Comment: @LuísFerreira.  Thanks Luis, but I don't think it is applicable.

Comment: Can't you just check to see if the time is `00:00:00` and then choose to date format based on that? I don't see what the real issue is here.

Comment: @John.  That is what I am doing in my posted example.  I didn't know if the PHP date class has some built in method which will do so.

Comment: Why do you reformat the date into the same format? Cannot you just `str_replace(' 00:00:00', '', $d)`?

Comment: @JohnConde.  Okay, makes sense.  echoing the time seems more readable than using substr to find it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method seems fine, but you could also do this:

```
$f = 'Y-m-d' . (date('H:i:s', strtotime($d)) != '00:00:00' ? ' H:i:s' : '');
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/Cpfgig7R)

---

*Update:*

@zerkms makes a great point in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705011/display-php-time-if-not-000000/#comment-42003155). Why reformat into the same format? Unless you are going to use a different format than `Y-m-d`, then you might be better served not using a function at all, and just using `str_replace()`. Or you could simplify your function as such:

```
function formatDate($d)
{
    return str_replace(' 00:00:00', '', $d);
}
```

[**See demo 2**](http://codepad.org/b2azsd1l)

Comment: I will actually use different formats, not just the default.